# Who makes this desk?

Tags: desk

Who makes this desk?

[image]

Seen on this [Dwell article](http://www.dwell.com/rooms-we-love/article/inside-workspaces-7-creatives).

Comment: Google for hydraulic lift draftman's table.

Comment: I am under the impression it is a custom made desk based on the article.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a vintage one made by Nike Eskilstuna from Sweden.  Google is my friend.....